# Select only having count=2

Tags: sql-server-2008

--This is the code

```
create table #Test (Systemtraceno nvarchar(50),Bin nvarchar(50),SwitchCode nvarchar(50),
SwitchDesc nvarchar(50),[Description] nvarchar(50))

insert into #Test 
select SystemTraceno , Bin,SwitchCode,SwitchDesc,[Description]
from(
select A.SystemTraceNo, A.BIN,'' SwitchCode, '' SwitchDesc,''[Description]
from ATM035 A 
where a.TranDate = '20130924' and  MsgType = '0210' and TerminalID = '08880001'
and A.ProcessCode in ('011000','012000','013000') and A.ResponseCode = '0000' and A.BIN <> '502265' 
--group by A.SystemTraceNo, A.BIN
)x
group by SystemTraceNo,BIN,SwitchCode,SwitchDesc,[Description]
having COUNT(SystemTraceNo)=2

update #Test set SwitchCode = (select top 1 SwitchCode from ATM027 where Bin = #Test.Bin )
update #test set SwitchDesc = (select switchname from ATM016 where SwitchCode = #test.switchcode)
update #test set [Description] = (Select top 1 Description from ATM027 where BIN = #Test.Bin )

Select * from #test order by SwitchDesc asc
drop table #test
```

--,'301000','302000','303000'

i just wanted to select rows having SystemTrace number count = 2.I earlier had problems with aggregation and now this.Hoping you could help me out.Thanks in advance

Comment: your question needs to be clearer - add some test data - are you looking for two records with distinct `SystemTraceNo` in #Test ?

Comment: yes, let me put it this way:

-every successful transaction has 2 similar systemtraceno;it count as one transaction(one is for request and the other is the response)
I want to query systemtraceno count=2 because if it has more than 2 similar SystemTraceNo,it means it is a reversal transaction which i want to eliminate.

This is the result i want.i want to query all base on systemtraceno=2

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to get into your code but this is how it should be :

```
select customers.customerId 
from customers join orders on custumers.Id = orders.customerId
group by customers.customerId
having count(orders.id)=2
```

See section 2 here : (section 1 is for the one who said it's possible).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE2M3.png

Comment: Your link is exactly what i need but i need to select more columns base on count of just 1 column.Your example shows just 1 column.Thanks sir Royi

Answer (score 1):

@Royi: actually, i think it should be

```
select customers.customerId , count(orders.id) as num
from customers join orders on custumers.Id = orders.customerId
group by customers.customerId
having num=2
```

Comment: It will not compile. since select is done at the end.delete this before you get downvote by others. http://i.stack.imgur.com/aE2M3.png. please learn the order of execution an sql server query

Comment: well, I tried an equivalent query on my mysql in localhost and it worked, so it seems to me you have nothing to teach in this case. As far as I remember, the having clause restricts the resultset after the query is executed, unlike the where clause

Answer (score 0):

```
where systemtraceno in (select systemtraceno from #Test group by systemtraceno having count(systemtraceno) = 2)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: It selects all records with systemraceno count = 2, so it does give the answer to the question.

Comment: You already get the idea of what result i wanted. But it does not run yet because of these errors.Thanks in advance sir

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Column 'x.SystemTraceNo' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Answer (score 0):

I thin the problem is at

```
group by SystemTraceNo
```

when you want to use

```
COUNT(SystemTraceNo)=2
```

In short your insert code should be like this:

```
insert into #Test 
select A.SystemTraceno , A,Bin,'' SwitchCode,'' SwitchDesc,'' [Description]
from ATM035 A 
where a.TranDate = '20130924' and  MsgType = '0210' and TerminalID = '08880001'
and A.ProcessCode in ('011000','012000','013000') and A.ResponseCode = '0000' and A.BIN <> '502265'
group by A.BIN
having COUNT(SystemTraceNo)=2
```