# SQL Server CREATE TABLE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Student 
(
    StudentID int PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(30),
    Age int,
    Course varchar(30), 
    Year int,
    Address varchar(50),
    Phone varchar(12),
    Email varchar(50)
);
```

I was wondering how to run a query to show the year level and the number of students in each year level I need only to show year levels that have at least two students.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select only having count=2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19000127/select-only-having-count-2)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like homework assignment!

```
select year, count(1)
from Student
group by year
having count(1) >= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below. You need to `group by` year and `count` and `filter` where `count` `>=` `2`

```
select year, count(*) as count from student group by year having count >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Year,COUNT(StudentID) from Student GROUP BY Year having COUNT(studentID) > 2
```

since each student ID is for a unique student I assume you can count on them as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Year, count (*) from Student
group by Year
having count(*) > 1
```